# Improving performance on older Androids

Tags: html5, html-canvas, mobile

I'm learning to build html5 games for mobile. I'm worried about the FPS animation on older model Android... as I use a lot of `setTimeouts` to update certain aspects and would like some suggestions on other approaches I could adopt.

Any advice on making this run a bit smoother?

Comment: Have you tested it on older Android models? What have you tried to improve the performance already?